# What are difference between system security and software security

Tags: security, system

I'm really confused about the difference between system security and software security.

Could someone clearly explain this?

Comment: Many, many articles on such and more: https://www.google.com/search?q=system+security+vs+software+security, especially depending on how one defines the terms.

Answer (score 1):

Software security would be a part of System Security.  Like the lock on your door is part of your home security.

So system security is more of a holistic view which includes software security